# Prove that $ab+a+b > 0$ if $a<-2$ and $b<-2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I am interested in proving the following statement:

> If $a<-2$ and $b <-2$ prove that $ab+a+b > 0$.

I tried using the fact that $ab>4$ and $a+b<-4$, but I couldn't progress any further, so this approach won't help me. Could I have a hint on how to start?

Comment: Write $a=-2-u$ and $b=-2-v$ with positive numbers $u, v$ ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: $ab + a + b = (a+1)(b+1)-1$.

Comment: got it , thanks a lot. should I post the answer?

Comment: @haitham: That's up to you. Glad to be of help!

Answer (score 1):

Hint (mentioned in the comments by Martin R): Let $a=-2-u$ and $b=-2-v$, where $u$ and $v$ are positive numbers. Try substituting these values into the expression $ab+a+b$, and use the fact that $u$ and $v$ are positive to reach the desired conclusion.

---

This method is effectively the same as writing
\begin{align}
ab+a+b &= \overbrace{\bigl((a+2)-2\bigr)\bigl((b+2)-2\bigr)}^{=ab}+\overbrace{(a+2)+(b+2)-4}^{=a+b} \\[5pt]
&= (a+2)(b+2)-(a+2)-(b+2) \\[5pt]
&>0 \, .
\end{align}

Comment: I got it, I haven't seen the method before, That was so helpful,  thanks.

Comment: @haitham: No problem. I'm glad I could help. The idea behind this approach is that the inequality you are trying to prove is "tight" in the sense that if $a=b=-2$ then $ab+a+b=0$. This means that if $a$ and $b$ are a little bit below $-2$, then $ab+a+b$ will only be slightly greater than $0$. Introducing the letters $u$ and $v$ helps give an explicit expression for how much bigger than $0$ the expression $ab+a+b$ is, and when $u=v=0$, we get that $ab+a+b=0$.